# C# WPF throws System.InvalidOperationException when adding Row to Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and want to add data to it with code.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="WareneingangEinbuchenGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StueckzahlName" Header="Stückzahl" Binding="{Binding Stueckzahl}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Preis" Header="Preis" Binding="{Binding Preis}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Barcode" Header="Barcode" Binding="{Binding Barcode}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The data class:

```
    public class WareneingangGridData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Stueckzahl { get; set; }

    public double Preis { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

XAML.cs:

```
WareneingangEinbuchenGrid.Items.Add(new WareneingangGridData { Name = "Testname", Stueckzahl = 2, Preis = 12.3 , Barcode = "TestBarcode" });
```

The application throws a System.InvalidOperationException error when executing the XAML.CS.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Except that you should probably be setting ItemSource. Instead of Items.Add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I edited the XAML.cs:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            WareneingangEinbuchenGrid.Items.Add(new WareneingangGridData { Name = "Testname", Stueckzahl = 2, Preis = 12.3, Barcode = "TestBarcode" });
        }));
```